# java.lang.IllegalStateException: subscribeText must not be null

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, null

Ситуация следующая, мне нужно от гугла получать информацию о ценах подписки в разных регионах, это я делаю, callback'ом получаю цену в фрагменте и вывожу на экран.
Но в метрике у некоторых пользователей вылетает ошибка

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: subscribeText must not be null
    at .Fragments.AdsFragment$a.e(Unknown Source)
    at .Utils.d$b.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.billingclient.api.g0.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6311)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

Мой фрагмент выглядит так:

```
    class SubscribeFragment : Fragment(), SubscribePriceCallback {
        private var subscribeResourceText: String = ""

        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedState: Bundle?): View? {
            ProviderSubscription.getSubscriptionPrice(this)
            
            val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subscribe_fragment, container, false)
            subscribeResourceText = getString(R.string.subscribe_text)
          
            return view
        }

        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        override fun subscribeMonthPrice(price: String) {
            subscribeText!!.text = subscribeResourceText + price
        }

    }
```

Мой вопрос в следующем, из-за того что я вывожу текст не в onCreateView(), может нужно его по другому инициализировать например так:

```
    class SubscribeFragment : Fragment(), SubscribePriceCallback {
       
        private var subscribeText: TextView? = null
        private var subscribeResourceText: String = ""

        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedState: Bundle?): View? {
            ProviderSubscription.getSubscriptionPrice(this)
            
            val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subscribe_fragment, container, false)
            subscribeResourceText = getString(R.string.subscribe_text)
            subscribeText = view.findViewById(R.id.subscribeText)
          
            return view
        }

        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        override fun subscribeMonthPrice(price: String) {
            subscribeText!!.text = subscribeResourceText + price
        }

    }
```

Или это происходит из-за того что price прилетает null, хотя в таком случае если я правильно понимаю TextView все равно должен просто выводить строку из string.xml.
Так как у мне не удалось повторить ошибку, я не знаю может ли это быть связанно именно с возвращаемой ценной, если так подскажите пожалуйста почему может прилетать null?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Инициализация текстового поля может происходить так:

```
lateinit var subscribeText: TextView
```

дальше в `onCreateView()`:

```
subscribeText = view.findViewById(R.id.subscribeText)
```

Во вторых получение информации и сеттинг ее в виджет нужно проводить уже после присваивания значения переменной виджета. Мне почему-то кажется что эта строка:

```
ProviderSubscription.getSubscriptionPrice(this)
```

сетит текст в ваш виджет. Переместите ее после присваивания значения и все должно заработать нормально. Просто вы пытаетесь установить текст в переменную у которой нет значения, поэтому и падает на `null`. Так же как вариант можно использовать syntetics (пример):

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

и дальше просто сетите текст:

```
subscribeText.text = "..."
```

[Вот](https://www.journaldev.com/64/android-textview-using-kotlin) есть хороший туториал по работе с textView